# uTorrent - adware / malware on download and install - Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: google-chrome, bittorrent, malware-removal, adware, malware-detection

I recently downloaded uTorrent (for the more ethically concerned: to get a wikipedia data dump as the official download server kept terminating my download, not to rip off copyright holders...), and as soon as the installation had finished my browsers were suddenly using Yahoo instead of google as their default search engine.

I've changed it back to google in the browser settings, but I'm concerned it's done all sorts of other nasties. Can anyone help me

- Understand what I might have installed
- Get rid of anything bad

I downloaded my copy of uTorrent from http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/mac, and simply clicked through the installation wizard.

I would rather manually remove any suspect files/revert any changed settings than use a tool. But totally open to suggestions of good tools if other people have had success with them before.

Comment: You didn't by any chance download from Sourceforge? [Compare this about FileZilla downloads from Sourceforge](http://httpshaming.tumblr.com/post/95068402386/filezilla-sourceforge-installer-insecure): *"This Sourceforge malware installer by default makes Yahoo your homepage on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, and makes Yahoo your tab page in Safari and installs a commercial cloud backup solution called ZipCloud."*

Comment: Even if you did download from SF, did you read the installation options or blindly click **Next Agree Next Accept Next Next**? And it's best to download from official site, not 3rd party sites like SF. But then again, I suggest staying away from uTorrent 3 as it has become commercialized crapware, no longer the goodness that was once synonymous with the name. Now I use good clients like qBittorrent (Windows) and Flud (Android).

Comment: Hi, it was from here http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/mac - all looked so shiny and legitimate :(

Comment: @ADTC I'm ashamed to admit I just clicked next repeatedly.

Comment: @Jake_Howard Yeah you gotta kick that habit. Will solve 90% of post-install problems. Anyway your best bet is to just reset your browser settings. *(Disclaimer: Percentage is rhetoric, not statistically validated.)*

Comment: @ADTC If you believe that is an answer to the question, then please post it as an answer so we can vote on it properly (and it can be accepted if it does solve the OP's problem). You might also want to describe *how* to reset the browser settings.

Comment: @ADTC Yup - you're quite right. TBH, it's the first time i've not used a package manager to install something in a very long time. Resetting chrome and firefox worked. Can't work out how to do it on safari, but I never use it anyway...Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Jake_Howard [How to reset Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6609131). Also be sure to check your installed apps and running processes for suspects. I posted my comments as answer. If you find it helpful, please upvote (up arrow). If it has solved your problem, please accept (check mark). Thanks :)

Comment: @ADTC - Hi, I've tried to upvote but until I have 15 rep it won't show up. Sorry (I think when I go over 15 rep it will automatically update).

Comment: There ya go - 3 upvotes on your question gives you the requisite Rep to vote up

Comment: @Jake_Howard Thanks :) It doesn't automatically update. You have to try again, now that you have enough rep. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try these:**

- Edit your browser settings manually
- Reset your browser settings to the default
- Check if any new software is now available which you didn't explicitly install
- Uninstall the offending software and repeat the above
- Look through running processes and kill any suspects (Please be very careful here. If you don't know what you're doing, call an expert.)

***As an extra tip:*** Kick the habit of clicking through installation wizards. Always scrutinize each step *(except the License Agreement, of course** `:P`*)* and check if there are any default options you need to change. Common examples are "Install and try *AwesomeCrapIDontNeed* for 30 days!" and "Set *AwesomeSearchIDontTrust* as my default search engine".

<sup>* As @Doc explains, you should pay attention to the EULA you are agreeing to. Even if you're not going to read the entire legal mumbo-jumbo, at least give it a cursory glance to make sure the License Agreement is for the software you want to install, rather than something sneaky like Yahoo browser toolbar. If the EULA is for something unwanted, you are likely to find an option to disagree (and NOT install that) but continue with installation of the software you want.</sup>

Comment: Found: /Users/<your-username>/Library/Application Support/Spigot/ApplicationManager --protect running as a process for other people who come across this problem. You have to remove the folder first and then kill it (rm -rf /Users/j<your-username>/Library/Application Support/Spigot) then kill -9 PID (which you can get from ps -ef | grep Spigot)

Comment: @Jake_Howard Good find. Spigot is a known PUP. (Removal instructions for [Windows](http://www.lavasoft.com/mylavasoft/company/blog/how-to-remove-search-protect-by-spigot) and [Mac](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-spigot/))

Comment: The utorrent osx installer has two panels that resemble an EULA, and are, but for Yahoo's sketchy activities. Yahoo has gone from 'lame' to 'extremely sketchy' in my books, because of this practice. And I'm now boycotting uTorrent due to their involvement as well. It's unfortunate. I used homebrew to install some other client, "xtorrent".

Comment: @Doc Good point. I will make a note about it.

Comment: As of today, there is no disclosure of any of this. You run the downloaded app, and everything gets installed

Comment: @Marcin yeah uTorrent has gotten shittier than ever with severe commercialization. I have made my move to [**qBittorrent**](http://www.qbittorrent.org/) which is clean and available for Windows, Mac OS X, Linux and couple others. And there is [**Flud**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delphicoder.flud&hl=en) for Android.